# Scratchy sound on "7 Seconds" Youssou N'Dour - ft. Neneh Cherry

Tags: meaning, sound

I thought I had a wrongly ripped mp3 of this song but even when I listen it on Spotify I can hear a [jump/interruption/scratch between 4:07 - 4:09](http://youtube.com/watch?v=pTIBjds39kM&t=4m5s) it's really annoying, why this happened to the song? was a record studio mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Of all the versions that I found on the Spotify:

- Album [*7 Seconds: The Best Of Youssou N'Dour*](https://open.spotify.com/track/76D5nfZbYzZYfUZKGy73jy)
- Album [*Man*](https://open.spotify.com/track/6ujamBcBsjC0cpyeMr9xja)
- Album [*Africa Greatest Hit Songs, Vol. 1*](https://open.spotify.com/track/5gaZRB43gcso6SoWDHsWxR)
- Album [*The Guide (Wommat)*](https://open.spotify.com/track/0PrlpSOlCkA1SJlqaSzpou)

I failed to hear any scratches cuts/jumps, including on the 4:07-4:09. The track seems to play correctly without any glitches.

The [official YouTube VEVO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqCpjFMvz-k) seems using the cut version given its duration (4:31 on YouTube vs 5:05 on Spotify), and the corresponding timestamp seems to be at [3:55](https://youtu.be/wqCpjFMvz-k?t=3m55s). However, the track also seems to play correctly without any glitches/jumps.

Thus, my conclusion is: **the ripped MP3 seems to be corrupted, and then it got uploaded to the YouTube (never trust unofficial uploaders).**

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTIBjds39kM at 4:09 it's very clear the jump

Comment: The first link you added there is a pretty clear jump, it also breaks the song tempo or BPM, it's easily recognizable...

Comment: @Ivanzinho, the link "pTIBjds39kM" doesn't seem to be official, so it shouldn't be taken as reference.